# building for watchOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, for architecture i386

Tags: swift, xcode7, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

- we have xcode 7.1.1, MobileFirst 7.1 and followed below link but for our hybrid application with apple watch (swift)

[https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#localMethod][1]

Below is complete error received while we added WorklightAPI

"WorklightAPI/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation.framework/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation(WLProcedureInvocationData.o), building for watchOS simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you build for watchOS1 or watchOS2? Currently watchOS2 is not supported

Comment: Your question is not clear... can you please provide details of the issue your are facing.